# Why is UIApplication not working in my Mac App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, openurl

i am using openURL for my iphone apps, works perfectly, but now i want to use it on mac, normally, i use this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
```

and it works perfectly in Xcode for iPhone app, but when doing a mac app, it gets me this error:

> `"UIApplication" undeclared (first use in this function)`

So help anyone?

Comment: UI library is used only for iPhone, iPad and iPod touch device development.And NSApplication is only used for mac desktop development applications. Therefore you must have used NSApplication instead of UIApplication.

Answer (score 19):

As others have said, `UIApplication` is part of UIKit, a Cocoa Touch framework for iOS. On the Mac, you have to use AppKit, a Cocoa framework for Mac OS X, which provides [`NSApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

That being said, if you want to open a URL you need to use [`NSWorkspace`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't use UIApplication. You need to use [NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Comment: wow so fast :D btw, where are the IBActions in interfacebuilder? i created them (appdelegate.h, then .m)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by asking where IBAction in InterfaceBuilder are. You just link IBAction with delegates on the inspector.

Comment: i mean where are the actions?i know where they normally are in IB, look at my screenshot http://min.us/mvjgBiM

Comment: You got here first, tío, he's all yours ;)

Answer (score 2):

try [NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/)